# Can't clone bitbucket repo locally

Tags: bash, github, bitbucket, git-clone

I set up my SSH key for my account.

When I run git clone in my terminal I usually get Forbidden fatal: could not read from remote repository.

Running `ssh-add -l` shows the correct authenticated agent.
Running `git clone` is now asking for my passphrase with the above error message.
Saying "please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

I ran `ps` to make sure there was only one authenticated agent

The `clone` command is `git clone git@bitbucket.org:<filepath>.git`

Comment: Please send the clone command. You may have used http instead of ssh

Comment: I added the git clone command. It's not https though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should:

- not be `git@bitbucket.org:<filepath>.git`
- but `git@bitbucket.org:<account>/<projectname>.git`

you can use:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
```

You will see which key SSH is using.
Make sure the public key has been [registered to your Bitbucket account settings](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/#SetupanSSHkey-#installpublickeyStep3.AddthepublickeytoyourAccountsettings).

But the OP adds:

> It's private and I'm not the owner. Does something need to be updated with access settings by the owner?

Then yes, your account [needs to be granted access in that repository by its owner](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/grant-repository-access-to-users-and-groups/).

Comment: my ssh key is added to my bitbucket account settings. And my bad. The clone URL is git@bitbucket.org:<account>/<projectname>.git

Comment: @ocom Is it a private repository? Do you own that repository?

Comment: It's private and I'm not the owner. Does something need to be updated with access settings by the owner?